# A Die is Rolled 3 times, what is the probability that a six is rolled at least once when the order doesn't matter?

Tags: probability, combinations

I figured I could use the binomial formula to solve this problem but then remembered it only works when the order does matter (repeated combinations are included). Is there a formula that does not account for the repeated combinations and that could help me solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: What’s the probability that no sixes come up?

Comment: When the order does matter, I know it would be 0.4822 because it's the total number of combinations which result in no sixes appearing (5*5*5*5) divided by the total number of combinations (6*6*6*6). However, I'm confused on how it would work when the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, as others indicate, easier to consider probability that no sixes occur and then subtract from $1$. So you should learn from this that when you see "at least one" you should consider the complementary scenario "none". Or even just that you should always have the complementary scenario in mind no matter what -- just another tool in your tool kit.

Comment: There is a lot about your Question that calls out for correction.  You stated a problem, at least tersely, in the title but leave out any problem statement in the body of the Question.  The remarks you make in the body are not correct (the binomial formula involves combinations, not *permutation* where order does matter).  The calculation you give in the Comment under the Question shows you've tried an approach and should be included in the body, but your Comment seems to address rolling a die *four times*, not the three times mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 4):

It's simpler to consider the complementary probability: the probability that no sixes are rolled is $(\frac{5}{6})^3$, so the probability that at least one six is rolled is $1-(\frac{5}{6})^3$.

If you instead use the method you suggested in your question, the result will be
$$ {3\choose 1}\frac{1}{6}\Big(\frac{5}{6}\Big)^2+{3\choose 2}\Big(\frac{1}{6}\Big)^2\frac{5}{6}+{3\choose 3}\Big(\frac{5}{6}\Big)^3$$

It follows from the binomial theorem that these two answers are in fact equal.

Answer (score 0):

The trick with "order doesn't matter" is to ask "to whom doesn't it matter and why?"

> A Die is Rolled 3 times, what is the probability that a six is rolled at least once when the order doesn't matter?

Why doesn't order matter?   Because, the observer loses track of which die is which and only keeps *count* of the faces that occur.   However, the *dice* roll the same whether we keep track of them or not.   They don't care whether or no order matters to the observer.

You can use the same sample space of $6^3$ *outcomes*; it is only the description of the *events* (and how we measure them) that is affected by "order doesn't matter."

Thus $~\mathsf P(\text{at least one six})~{~=~1-\mathsf P(\text{no sixes on the three dice}) \\ ~=~1- 5^3/6^3} $